# How to replace array value with hash value?

Tags: ruby

I have an array

`@a = ["a","b","c","d"]`

and this is my hash

`@a_hash ={"b"=> ["1","2","3"]}`

now I want to replace the value of the `"b"` with `@a_hash` value into the array.

my expected result is

`@a = ["a",["1","2","3"],"c","d"]`

How can i get this in ruby?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous because you have told us whether `@a` is known to contain exactly one element `"b"` and if not, what is to be done. You can provide an example to clarify your intent but it is not a substitute for a complete and unambiguous statement of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`#fetch`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/fetch) method

```
@a = ["a","b","c","d"]
#=> ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

@a_hash ={"b"=> ["1","2","3"]}
#=> {"b"=>["1", "2", "3"]}

@a.map! { |e| @a_hash.fetch(e, e) }
#=> ["a", ["1", "2", "3"], "c", "d"]
```

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps like this:

```
a = ["a","b","c","d"]
a_hash ={"b"=> ["1","2","3"]}

a.map! { |x| a_hash[x] || a } 
a #=> ["a",["1","2","3"],"c","d"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array#index`:

```
@a[@a.index("b")] = @a_hash["b"]
@a
#=> ["a", ["1", "2", "3"], "c", "d"]
```

It's probably the fastest solution if you have only one occurrence of 'b'.
For each occurrence of "b":

```
@a.map! {|e| @a_hash["b"] if e == "b"}
```

Comment: #1 does not account for the possibility that `@a` does not have an element `"b"`. I do like the use of `index`, however, as it terminates as soon as it finds a match (if there is one), unlike the selected answer, which enumerates all elements of `@a`. Just add a step: `i = @a.index("b"); @a[i] = @a_hash["b"] if a` (which returns `nil` if `i.nil? #=> true`).

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign the element to be the value of the hash key:

```
@a[1] = @a_hash['b']
```

That's it.

Comment: You can simplify: `@a = ["a", ["1", "2", "3"], "c", "d"]`. :-)